# Creating a custom route hierarchy ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My current url routing is:

```
website.com/start/id
website.com/upload/id
```

These routes are wizard steps.
My controllers are named `StartController, UploadController` and my View structure is `~Views/Start/Index.cshtml, ~/Views/Upload/Index.cshtml`

The client has requested that he wants the url structure to be:

```
website.com/build/start/id
website.com/build/upload/id
```

**Wishes:**

- I do not want use a "[vanity url](http://mazzimo-in-london-eng.blogspot.mx/2013/03/vanity-url-on-aspnet-mvc.html)" because I want to use @Html.ActionLink and @Url.Action to render my urls whenever possible so I can rename controllers and controller methods later and have those "connected" @Html.ActionLink and @Url.Action update.
- I do want to have all my methods in a single parent BuildContoller that references a nested View folder structure having my controller methods returing the following views: `return View("~/Views/Build/Start/Index.cshtml")`. I want to be able to have my View physical structure map/match to my controller naming conventions so return View(); works in controller methods.

**My Question:**

Is there way that I can respect my "Wishes" above and achieve this custom Url Structure without having to create a BuildController that contains both my StartController methods and my UploadController methods?

I have no problem creating a BuildController or changing the physical structure of my View folders and or controllers but I want to respect the ability of `@Url.Action("Start", "Build")` and not have to write "manually" in my code "`build/start`" and, more importantly, keep my `StartController` and `UploadController` code because I do not want a long massive bunch of code in my BuildController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would switch to attribute routining. You will have to change your ActionLink methods to RouteLink methods but it will work the same way.

Add the attribute

```
[Route("build/start/{id:int}", Name = "WizardStep1")]
```

for each controller method (changing the route appropriately).

To generate a link, use RouteLink:

```
@Html.RouteLink("WizardStep1", ...)
```

Replacing the ... with the additional code you need to set the URL attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My [System.Web.MVC.Route()] attribute is only accepting one parameter, the route, the second parameter, the route Name it does not like, is this perhaps an ASP.NET MVC 6 feature? I am definitely using ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: I changed your answer to "Name = "WizardStep1" to fix